# What is the difference between mysqli_begin_transaction () and mysqli_autocommit

Tags: php, mysqli, transactions

Does `mysqli_begin_transaction()`  achieve the same functionality as `mysqli_autocommit ()` ?

Comment: mysqli_autocommit  mean that after each query trhe result is immediatally commited .. (so you can't roolback)   mysqli_begin_transaction mean  that a transaction begin  .. then performed  the query you can commit or roolback them

Comment: Do I have to set autocommitt to FALSE before I call `mysqli_begin_transaction ()` or it handles that on it's own and turn it on after commiting

Comment: You shold better ask about the diff. from `mysqli_autocommit` and `mysqli_commit`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

- `mysqli_autocommit()` sets autocommit mode permanently. It means that if you set it to 0 and then commit a transaction, the mode will remain 0.
- `mysqli_begin_transaction()` begins a single transaction. It means after commit the mode reverts to its previous state.
  besides, it allows you to fine tune a transaction, starting it in one of the following modes:

  - MYSQLI_TRANS_START_READ_ONLY.
  - MYSQLI_TRANS_START_READ_WRITE
  - MYSQLI_TRANS_START_WITH_CONSISTENT_SNAPSHOT
    You can read on the modes in mysql documentation, https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/commit.html

Comment: I have implemented my code using your explanation and so far it's working  the way I want it except that Xammp is throwing me error saying that the current Server does not support READ and WRITE ONLY minimum should be `5.6.5`and my PHP scripts are not redirecting user remain on same page.I will try to host it on a live server.One more question:I have multiple users reading and writing the same row with row level locking but i cant find a way to simulate multiple users , are there any tools or ways you can suggest?

Comment: Better ask it as a separate question