# MySQLi begin_transaction & autocommit

Tags: php, mysqli

I have searched through several answers but cannot find what I need.

I want to use transactions with `mysqli`. Ive seen that most examples use `$mysqli->autocommit(false);`. Would using `$mysqli->begin_transaction();` have the same effect as turning the `autocommit` off? When I `commit` will it automatically be turned back on? Lastly why can I not use something similar to below:

```
$sql = ('
    START TRANSACTION;

    SELECT
    ...
');
```

I plan to combine my transactions with prepared statements.

Comment: Does that answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/a/42629072/1839439

Comment: @Dharman yes thank you!

Comment: You could also take a look at [What is the benefit of using “begin_transaction” method in MySQLi?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48812724/what-is-the-benefit-of-using-begin-transaction-method-in-mysqli)